# Regex to find string starting with % and ending with .DESCR

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a very large file of source code loaded in Notepad++, and I am trying to use it's regex search capabilities to find all places where a property is used.

I need to find all places where a property `DESCR` is set. I tried searching for just `.DESCR` without regex, but there are far too many results for me to sift through. I know that the code I am looking for will either be prefaced with `%This.` or `&` and some variable name, followed by `.DESCR =`.

I've tried using [RegExr](http://regexr.com/) to construct the regex, but it isn't finding the strings I want. I've looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean) to try to understand regex more, but I am missing something still.

EDIT:  More descriptions
Here are examples of something I would be looking for:
`%This.oPosition.DESCR = &DATAREC.Y_BUSINESS_TITLE.Value;`
`%This.data.DESCR = "";`
`&data.DESCR = "Analyst";`
`&oPosition.DESCR = &DATAREC.DESCR.Value;`

It should not, however, match on these:
`&P_NODE_PIN_DESCR = &NODE_PIN_DESCR;`
`&qLang.Descr = &sDescr;`

I know that I am *way* off base, but here is what I have tried:

`(\%This\.|\&[A-Z]+)\.DESCR =` This doesn't pick up anything.
`\%This.|\&(A-Z)+.DESCR` This picks up on `%This` but nothing following, and doesn't find anything prefaced by `&`.
`\%This.\w.DESCR =|\&\w+.DESCR =` It looks like it's working on RegExr, but it doesn't match properly in Notepad++ (It matches on things like `&ACCT_DESCR =`)

I'm just not familiar enough with regex to understand what I am missing.

EDIT:
Notepad++ search settings:
[image]

Comment: Could you provide some samples of what you want to match. Are you sure you checked regular expression as search mode?

Comment: @SebastianProske post edited. Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for `(?:%this\.|&)\w+\.DESCR =` according to your description. Please untick *match case* in the search dialog (except you are only searching for `This`, but not for `this` or similar.

- `(?:%this\.|&)` matches either `%this.` or `&` both literally (but case insensitive)
- \w+ matches one or more word characters, thus letters, numbers or underscore. You could also use `[a-z]+` to be stricter and only consider letters - or `[a-zA-Z]+` when searching case sensitive
- `\.DESCR =` matches `.DESCR =` literally. If you only want to match DESCR case sensitive, you can use an inline modifier for case sensitivity: `\.(?-i)DESCR =`

Comment: So, when I remove case sensitive in Notepad++ it also finds things like `qLang.Descr = ` which I don't want. How can I fix that?

Comment: @CacheStaheli see my edit concerning the inline modifier

Answer (score 0):

Here's why your attempts didnt work:

1. You are checking for lowercase only. [A-Z] You need to check for [a-zA-Z] or use the insensitive modifier /i (in this case represented by the "match case" check box
2. When using the or simple it refers to everything after it until it reaches the end or a closed parentheses

Here's the regex you need

```
(\%This\.|\&)[A-Za-z]+\.DESCR
```

If you want to capture only .DESCR you can use this non-capturing groups like so:

```
(?:(?:\%This\.|\&)[A-Za-z]+)(\.DESCR)
```

You can then use the back-reference $1 or \1 to replace .DESCR in these specific appearances

https://regex101.com/r/fW9lZ2/2